# .Net MVC Cannot remove Validation message using jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have simple form a dropdown list and a textbox. When the page is loaded textbox is disabled. If 'Other' is selected from dropdown list, then textbox is enabled and I add 'required' rule to textbox as I don't want user to enter something in the text box. When 'Other' is selected and if Create button is clicked, I can see validation error message but I cannot remove that message after user has typed something in the empty textbox. Here is how it looks:

[image]

Here is my model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace validatetextbox.Models
{
    public class Manager
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Other City")]
        [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
        public string OtherCity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Controller method is

```
// GET: Managers/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    //populate Gender dropdown
    List<SelectListItem> c = new List<SelectListItem>();
    c.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "-- Please Select --", Value = "" });
    c.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "New York", Value = "New York" });
    c.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Miami", Value = "Miami" });
    c.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Other", Value = "Other" });

    ViewBag.Cities = c;
    return View();
}
```

My view is as follows:

```
@model validatetextbox.Models.Manager

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 }

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Manager</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.City, ViewBag.Cities as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherCity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OtherCity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OtherCity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#OtherCity').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#City').change(function () {
            if ($('#City option:selected').text() != 'Other') {
                $("#OtherCity").rules("remove", "required");
                $('#OtherCity').prop('disabled', true);
            } else {
                $('#OtherCity').prop('disabled', false)
                $("#OtherCity").rules("add", "required");
            }
        });
});
</script>

}
```

Comment: Use a conditional validation attribute e.g. a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` attribute so that you get client and server side validation

Answer (score 0):

To keep your existing code - you can [remove the rules](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) from the text box on document ready. Also - side note - keep quotation marks consistent.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#OtherCity').prop('disabled', true);
        // Remove any rules
        $('#OtherCity').rules("remove");
        $('#City').change(function () {
            if ($('#City option:selected').text() != 'Other') {
                //Also tidy up `"` to `'`
                $('#OtherCity').rules("remove", "required");
                $('#OtherCity').prop('disabled', true);
            } else {
                $('#OtherCity').prop('disabled', false)
                //Also tidy up `"` to `'`
                $('#OtherCity').rules("add", "required");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Another thing you could try is - add the class optional to the editor - the label will display and the visibility and validation requirement will be controlled by the JS:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherCity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10 optional">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OtherCity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OtherCity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    // This will hide the field
    $('.optional').hide();
    // This makes the value optional
    $('#OtherCity').attr("data-val", "false");
    $('#City').change(function () {
        if ($('#City option:selected').text() == 'Other') {
            // Show the text editor
            $('.optional').show();
            // This makes the value required
            $('#OtherCity').attr("data-val", "true");

        } else {
            $('.optional').hide();
            $('#OtherCity').attr("data-val", "false");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yvette, it doesn't work. Still the result is same as the screenshot.

Comment: Hiding OtherCity textbox works fine but I don't want to hide. When I change from Other to Miami, the Othercity is disabled as it should except the 'This field is required.' is visible under the textbox. When I click the Create button, form is submitted and City and OtherCity info is inserted into the table. It is very strange.